# Make Fn key from mac keyboard work on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, gnome, mac

I am using a mac keyboard slim aluminium with Ubuntu 11.10, the keyboard has <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> as controls for increasing and decreasing the volume. On boot the keys work as F keys but I would like them to behave as sound controls with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I followed the relevant guides from previous answers but nothing worked. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell.

Answer (score 2):

Fn-key seems to work on older A1314-keyboards, but not with 2011 model (the one with two batteries, F4 key has six rectangles instead of speedometer).

2011 version of Apple Wireless Keyboard works fine with a Mac, but no luck with Ubuntu so far.

Answer (score 1):

i used the amd+64+mac.iso for the installation, all function-keys work out-of-the-box.
the image can be downloaded at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.10/release/